# Make an application independent from windows's culture

Tags: vb.net

I'm creating an application in VB.NET, .NET 4.0.

This application uses too often the `DateTime` type.

The problem is that I want to work with dates in a specific format `dd/MM/yyyy`.

If a set ( in Windows ) the correct Regional and settings everything is ok.
But if user change this Windows configurations, my application fails.
So is there any way to make my application independent from what is configured in Windows for Regional and settings ?
Thank you !

Comment: Dates don't have a format. If your application fails when the culture changes then it's because you're doing something wrong. Format is only an issue for dates when you are converting to or from a `String` and there's no reason for that to have an effect on your application. For instance, if you want the user to edit dates in a WinForms UI then you use a `DateTimePicker`.  It can display the date to the user in whatever format they expect based on system settings and you just use the `Value` property, which is type `DateTime`, and the format has no effect at all.

Comment: Explain to us what you're doing and we will explain to you exactly what you're doing wrong.  Anywhere in your application that the code depends on a specific format, you're almost certainly doing something wrong there.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I'm reading dates as strings from an text file , and after I convert them.         Dim dt As Date = Date.ParseExact(s, "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) , If for example s="25/12/2018" , this line of code is ok with some Regional settings but produce exception with some others , but for my application rule this is a correct Date.

Comment: `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`

Comment: If you don't want to be affected by the current culture then why specify the current culture when doing the conversion? Don't specify a culture at all, i.e. use `Nothing` for the third argument.  I would imagine that using the invariant culture or a specific culture that uses that date format, e.g. en-GB, would work too.

Comment: `Dim dt As Date = Date.ParseExact(s, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`. If you can change the way dates are stored in these files, use the more general/invariant format `"yyyy/MM/dd"`, so you don't have to rely on any specific format and the dates will always be parsed correctly using `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`. You need to work with `DateTime` objects, not with strings. Ever.

Comment: @Jimi even your code works with some regional settings , but with some others does not work.

Comment: If you mean the `Date.ParseExact(s, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` part, that depends on the input format, the `s` value. This value must be provided in the format specified in the `ParseExact` method. If `s = "1/1/2018"`, this will generate an error. The regional/local settings are not considered in this conversion, only the string format, which must be convertible using the given format converter. If `s` is always formatted as "yyyy/MM/dd",  `ParseExact(s, "yyyy/MM/dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` will succeed. If you have a specific error, post the values that reproduce it.

Comment: @Jimi Try it with s="25/12/2018"

Comment: That can't possibly fail. If the conversion format is `"dd/MM/yyyy"`. Post the whole section of code you're using for this; updating your question, not in comments.

Comment: Based on my testing, it doesn't matter what culture you use. I suggest that you provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

I used to have a similar problem some time ago, but not a `DateTime` issue, was more related to calculations, the decimal point `.`. Although some of the examples in the above comments worked fine, specifically the `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` I found it far easier to scrap all those and simply add this to my main form `Load`:

```
Application.CurrentCulture = New Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB")
```

Problem solved ;-)